# android equivalent of graphics

Tags: android, equivalent

Im trying to convert a java program to an android program. So the question is: What is the equivalent of graphics type variable on android. For example "protected Graphics entryGraphics;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has the `Canvas` class which is essentially the equivalent. For more information please see [the official 2D graphics guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html).

However `Canvas` uses the CPU to render the graphics. For GPU rendering and therefore better performance, you may want to check out [OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html).